kvm running windows is a postage stamp
Running windows in kvm on a 4k screen leaves windows 11 running the size of a postage stamp. In the windows VM, the display resolution says 1280x800, but is greyed out, meaning can't change it.
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

The only OS you mention is windows; why ask here?  If you're after help with your HOST system (which you don't mention except through implication due to kvm) you'll have to provide some specifics as to what you're using, as we don't support windows 11 (it's not Ubuntu).  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Edit your question and add the distro and version of Linux you are using.
